# Testing if mock was called with other mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to test if a mock object was called with another mock object.

```
@patch(__name__ + '.xero_helper.PublicCredentials')
@patch(__name__ + '.xero_helper.Xero')
def testGetValidPublicXeroInstance(self, XeroMock, CredentialsMock):
    xero_helper.get_xero_instance('abc')  # Do relevant stuff

    CredentialsMock.assert_called_with(**org.oauth_credentials)  # OK
    XeroMock.assert_called_once()  # OK
    XeroMock.assert_called_with(CredentialsMock)  # Not OK
```

The first two `assert`s pass, whereas the last one gives a

```
AssertionError: Expected call: Xero(<MagicMock name='PublicCredentials' id='4377636560'>)
Actual call: Xero(<MagicMock name='PublicCredentials()' id='4377382544'>)
```

What would be the correct way to verify the `XeroMock` was called with the `CredentialsMock`?

Comment: In future, please include the code under test too; I can work out from the assertion error what the problem is, but it'd be easier with the actual code (or a working replacement for it, that produces the same output). This is called a [MCVE].

Comment: Another alternative could be to restructure the code so there are alternatives ways to inject mocks besides through `@patch`.  A popular with could be dependency injection.  Perhaps `get_xero_instance` could accept `**kwargs` and allow the caller to provide a `CredentialsMock` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code *called* the `CredentialsMock` mock object, presumably to create an instance. Note the `()` in the resulting name:

```
<MagicMock name='PublicCredentials()' id='4377382544'>
#                                 ^^ called
```

while you passed in just the mock itself:

```
<MagicMock name='PublicCredentials' id='4377636560'>
#                                ^ not called
```

Test for the `return_value` result:

```
XeroMock.assert_called_with(CredentialsMock.return_value)
```